# Blazor Wasm notifiy parent component of state change

Tags: parent-child, blazor-webassembly

What code is needed to enable a Blazor child component to notify its parent component of state changes? I tried the following, which didn't work:

**Helper class**

```cs
    public class NotificationHandler
    {
        public event Action? Dispatcher;

        public void Notify() => Dispatcher?.Invoke();

        public void Attach(Action dispatcher) => Dispatcher += dispatcher;
        public void Release(Action dispatcher) => Dispatcher -= dispatcher;
    }
```

**Parent Component**

```cs
    @code
    {
        ChildComponent childComponent;
        StateNotifier stateNotifier;

        protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            stateNotifier.Attach(StateHasChanged);
            return base.OnInitializedAsync();
        }
        
        // Overloading StateHasChanged() - does it work this way?
        protected new void StateHasChanged() // never gets called
        {
            DoSomething(); 
            base.StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    <div>
        <ChildComponent StateNotifier="stateNotifier" />
    </div>
```

**Child Component**

```cs
    @code
    {
        [Parameter]
        public StateNotifier stateNotifier { get; set; }

        async void OnSomeUserAction()
        {
            stateNotifier.Notify();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What code is needed to enable a Blazor child component to notify its
> parent component of state changes?

Simplest way is to use an EventCallback.

**Child Component**

```
<button @onclick=NotifyParent>Notify</button>

@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback OnSomethingHappened { get; set; }

    async Task NotifyParent()
    {
        await OnSomethingHappened.InvokeAsync();
    }
}
```

**Parent Component**

```
<ChildComponent OnSomethingHappened=@HandleSomethingHapppened />

@code {
    async Task HandleSomethingHappened()
    {
        await DoSomethingElse();
     
        // StateHasChanged() not needed when handling an event
        // The Blazor engine will automatically
        // run an Html diff after handling a component
        // event.

        // StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's probably the best solution.